# Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected @header($redirect)

Tags: php, redirect

```
/* set the correct redirect */
$redirect="Location: ".$this->_encodeRedirectURL($url);

/* add the cookie if needed */
if ($cookie!=null)
  $redirect.="\nSet-Cookie: $cookie";

if (defined("DEBUG_LIB"))
{
  print("DEBUG: lib: redirect header=$redirect<br>\n");
  phpinfo();
  exit;
}
header($redirect);
```

I get the "new line detected" error after login while being redirected to member page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says. There may only be one header statement per header() call. If you want to send more headers, use the header function multiple times with the seconed parameter set to "false":

```
header('Location: ...');
header('Set-Cookie: ...', false);
```

Comment: And its for security reasons.

Comment: /* set the correct redirect */
       header('Location:.$this->_encodeRedirectURL($url)');

    /* add the cookie if needed */
    if ($cookie!=null)
       header("Set-Cookie: $cookie\n",false);

    if (defined("DEBUG_LIB"))
    {
      print("DEBUG: Lib: redirect header=$redirect<br>\n");
      phpinfo();
      exit;
    }
    exit;

Comment: So I tried this and get "web page not found" but no header error. But if I hit refresh then the redirected page comes up

Comment: Volker, thank you. Took several hours to play with context but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```html
/* set the correct redirect */
$redirect="Location: ".$this->_encodeRedirectURL($url);

/* add the cookie if needed */
if ($cookie!=null)
{
      header($redirect);
      $redirect="Set-Cookie: $cookie";
}
if (defined("DEBUG_LIB"))
{
  print("DEBUG: lib: redirect header=$redirect<br>\n");
  phpinfo();
  exit;
}
header($redirect);
exit;
```

Comment: I moved a header redirect up into the if section and bracketed it and it worked. Thanks for the help.